# Как записать данные в сессию

Tags: php

Каким образом записать в сессию и потом получить из нее данные?
Дело в том что записать нужно **ID** чего-либо(например товаров). 
id одного товара записать знаю как, а вот как несколько - не пойму. Массив наверное нужно создавать...

Буду благодарен за примеры реализации!

Comment: Ну дык `$_SESSION['test'] = ['test1' => 1, 'test2' => 2];` к примеру

Comment: @АлексейШиманский хм, не понятно, как записывать товары по одному. то есть, пользователь нажимает на товар, ему добавляется id товара в сессию, и так можно добавлять сколько угодно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял, допустим в сессии есть поле, которое хранит `id` продуктов..

Назовем его `$_SESSION['product_ids']`

Добавляем очередной идентификатор так:  `array_push($_SESSION['product_ids'], 666);`

Так в `$_SESSION['product_ids']` будут добавляться все новые `id`

Конечно, в начале надо добавить в сессию поле с таким ключом.

```
if (!$_SESSION['product_ids'])
    $_SESSION['product_ids'] = [];
```

Итого:

```
 session_start();
 if (!$_SESSION['product_ids'])
    $_SESSION['product_ids'] = [];
 array_push($_SESSION['product_ids'], 666);
 print_r($_SESSION['product_ids']);
```

Comment: Алексей, сделал так на странице для того чтобы протестировать `session_start();

array_push($_SESSION['product_ids'], 666);

echo $_SESSION['product_ids'];` но ничего не выводит. Скажите пожалуйста, что я упустил?

Comment: @Денис Перезагрузите страницу наверное)) А вообще, так как это массив, то надо не `echo`, а `print_r($_SESSION['product_ids']);`

Comment: Теперь на экране **array_push** пишет. но не как не добавляемый id

Comment: @Денис Надо чтоб ключ был, куда добавляете. Дополнил ответ, чтоб для наглядности